# What is the best secure, complete process for setting up CentOS server for WHM/cPanel?

Tags: linux, apache, centos, cpanel, whm

**Intro**
I know very little about Mac Terminal, and my knowledge of command line is limited to tinkering around in DOS when I was a kid. Really an amateur here.

**Main Issue**
I am setting up a VPS on Linode, to manage multiple client websites, as this is one of the best, most cost-effective solutions our web development business has discovered.

After installing Ubuntu distro and setting it up nicely according to a really great tutorial, I discovered that cPanel doesn't support Ubuntu. So, deleted that configuration and started installing CentOS. Only problem is there doesn't seem to be any good, simple info out there on how to set it up.

Essentially, I'd like to limit the use of command-line to absolute minimum, while still having a secure server, and then installing WHM/cPanel. After that I'd like to forget that Terminal/command line exists.

I cannot find a single complete resource/walk-through on how to do this. Do I need a PHD in something? If someone knows of a good way to do this, I would love to know.

**EDIT** I'd like to install Apache2, PHP, MySQL, and maybe a couple of other programs if that makes any difference (Basically LAMP stack) - The main issue I have is finding a good, secure way of installing and configuring CentOS, and for it to happily accept the installation of WHM/CPanel. So instructions I've seen on the web are either unsecure, incomplete, or assume a high level of understanding of Linux programming.

Comment: WHM/cPanel is a commercial product - is there no such guide on their website? (Aside: are you offering hosting services commercially? If so, do be cautious - it generally requires expert knowledge to do well). FWIW, when I set up a general web server that needs a point and click interface, I use Webmin every time.

Comment: @halfer this is interesting feedback. We sell hosting to commercial businesses, and manage it through WHM and cPanel. So far, so good. We're moving from HostGator to Linode. The sale of this hosting is not our core business. We are web marketing and development specialists.

Comment: If you're the only user of the control panel, then I'd say cPanel etc is a licensing cost you don't need. To be fair, it does sugar-coat some stuff, and perhaps Webmin is a bit less friendly, but Webmin is both stable and free.

Comment: I need to be able to be able to grant access to cpanel type interface for some of our clients, unfortunately. Webmin is more than a little bit user unfriendly. cPanel has a web 1.0 interface as it is. Webmin looks like it was designed to be as confusing and ugly as humanly possibe. Sure, its the ugly girl with nice personality, but no one's gonna want to use it, and we'd spend ages explaining it to our clients.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you will install cpanel bydefault apache, mysql php will install on server, you can install/upgrade apache and php with easyapache from whm or also from shell with below command:

> /script/easyapache

and follow instructions. You can also add http and php module with easyapache. You just need to install perl before installing cpanel.

Comment: That's not a very clear answer, but the best I'm likely to get on this. For anyone else who's looking for an answer: cPanel has it's own built in security features, so you don't need to harden your server before install. Just follow the install instructions on cPanel website. Just make a really impossible password for the root user in the initial SSH steps. cPanel likes a freshly installed Cento's with perl and nothing else installed basically.